# Js math is broken

Tags: javascript

Hi I don't understand that. output should be £112 but it's £1696 because it adds 16 and next to it 96.

```js
let output = 2
let cal = "£" + output * 8 + 96
console.log(cal)
```

Comment: Use template literals instead of `+` concatenation. `\`£${output * 8 + 96}\``

Comment: Math isn't broken when you're performing math operations.  You're concatenating strings.  Which isn't math.  What *mathematical value* do you expect `"some string" + 16` to produce?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you start your expression with a string, the `+` operator is used to concatenate. Try using parentheses:

```js
let output = 2
let cal = "£" + (output * 8 + 96)
```

It's also nice to use template syntax:

```js
let cal = `£${output * 8 + 96}`
```